# Django AppRegistryNotReady Error

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

Migrating my project from 1.8.5 to 1.9b1 cause next traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/.../env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And my manage.py is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.base")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I checked Django 1.9 update guide but it's don't provide any info on App loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally see a similar stack of error messages when the settings file can't be found. So in this case your `settings\base.py` file either can't be found or is missing some settings needed for django 1.9.

As this is a migrate, I am assuming that you are using virtualenv, and have pip installed django 1.9b1 into the new environment and are running the application there.

If this is the case then try creating a new "dummy" project to see what a clean django 1.9 settings file looks like.

Comment: I figure it out. It's because third part dependence - Wagtail CMS cause the problem. Thank you anyway.